# Pylint flags all files at the same line for import error

Tags: python, pylint

I have an issue with Pylint which reports the following (false-positive?) warning:

> standard import "import re" should be placed before "from astroid
> import MANAGER" pylint(wrong-import-order) [5,1]

and this in all my file at the same line (5).

I cannot find this line:

```
from astroid import MANAGER
```

anywhere in any of my files

**My settings** :

pylint 2.8.3
astroid 2.5.6
python 3.8.6

**VS Code** :

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "-------",
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins",
        "pylint_flask_sqlalchemy",
        "pylint_flask",
        "--max-line-length=80",
    ]
}
```

=> Is it a bug coming from pylint or does this line exist in one my my third party package like one of the flask extension ?

Answer (score 0):

It look like you're analysing [`astroid`, a pylint dependencies](https://github.com/PyCQA/astroid/blob/master/astroid/brain/brain_gi.py#L30) and not your own code. You should launch pylint on your own code and not the code installed in your virtualenv. Putting the correct path in  `"python.pythonPath": "-------",`, for example  `"python.pythonPath": "src/my_code",` should fix this.

Comment: My path is correct the  '--------------' were just here because I don't want to share where I store python ^^
So I still have the issue

Comment: Try pointing that to your own code not the python interpreter. The path is wrong if you don't share the path it's harder to help you.

Comment: C:\\Users\\viann\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python.exe

Comment: Yes look like you need to point to your own code root dir not, ``python.exe``.